# Python Selenium, error with loading up browser

Tags: python, selenium

I've looked all over for what must be a very simple solution to this problem. All I've been trying to do is load Google Chrome using selenium but I keep getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
```

I've looked at posts related to this problem and none seem to have a fix. So instead, I tried using Firefox, which led me to this error:

```
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'D:\\Programming\\Python Packages\\Selenium stuff\\geckodriver.exe'
```

Now I've checked, and the directory name is definitely not invalid for Firefox, And I have no clue what the chrome issue is. Any clues on what I might be missing here? Here's my simple code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox("D:\\Programming\\Python Packages\\Selenium stuff\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

I've made sure to check my versions of webdrivers are compatible with my browser versions, and I've tried changing the slashes "/" and "" in my code. No changes were made.

Comment: About Chrome, I think you should check the version of your Chrome and chromedriver.
About Firefox, try using "/" instead of "\" (ex: D://Programming//...)

Comment: Might want to look into webdriver manager. It makes this a lot easier for you.

Comment: driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:/Programming/Python Packages/Selenium stuff/geckodriver.exe') in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Along with Chrome version issue, you are missing the attribute to be given to initialize the browser `executable_path`

A sample snippet for Firefox browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Webdriver/geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

The same you can try with Chrome browser as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the file to an easier place to find, or directly copy the address from the file explorer. If none of that works, try a different browser or reinstall the driver.